# D3 bar graph Y-axis not appearing despite being in DOM

Tags: d3.js

When making a bar graph using d3, I tried adding a y-axis to display 2-decimal floats from 0 to 1. The method I used, which had worked previously, just results in the text elements showing up in the DOM but not actually appearing on the graph. How would I go about fixing this error?

Y-axis related code shown below.

```
var yscale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([height, 0]);
var yaxis = d3.axisLeft(yscale);
svg.append("g")
   .attr("id", "graphYAxis")
   .attr("transform", "translate ( " + 0 + "," + 0 + ")")
   .call(yaxis);
```

[image: Nothing appears]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the image provided with the question, it is evident that you have translated the **svg** element to (30,40) instead of the **g** element. As a result, your text is visible but located outside the **svg** element. To address this issue, it is advisable to adhere to the standard margin convention recommended by the D3.js library, as documented [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/margin-convention).

```
const containerWidth = 500   // total width including margins
const containerHeight = 400; // total height including margins
const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 };
const chartWidth = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;  // chart width after margin-left and margin-right
const chartHeight = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // chart height after margin-top and margin-bottom

// create and configure svg element
const svg = d3
  .create("svg")
  .attr("width", containerWidth)
  .attr("height", containerHeight)

// create a group within the svg element to apply margins
const chartGroup = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
  
 chartGroup.append("g")
 .attr("id", "graphYAxis")
 .call(yaxis);
```

**Please update the remaining portions of your code according to your requirements.**

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. The alignment is off, but that should be easily solvable - the text now displays properly. Thank you!